# Переход по ссылке только после всех записей в localStorage

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Я получаю данные по GitHub API на странице index,html, после чего записываю их в LocalStorage и хочу использовать на странице user.html

Но дело в том, что данные по ключу contributorsArr заносятся позже, чем по ключу RepoData, из за чего в случае перехода по ссылке на странице user.html я имею только данные по ключу RepoData

Как я могу совершить переход на user.html, чтобы не потерять никаких данных? То есть дождавшись всех записей в LocalStorage

```
const API = class {
    constructor() {
        this.URL = 'https://api.github.com';
        this.USER_PER_PAGE = 10;
    }
    getData = async (url) => {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Not enought data from : ${url}`);
        }
    }
    getRepoResult = (repoPath) => {
        return this.getData(`${this.URL}/repos/${repoPath}`);
    }
    getContributorsResult = (repoPath) => {
        return this.getData(`${this.URL}/repos/${repoPath}/contributors`);
    }
}
```

Здесь я жму на ссылку с названием репозитория и получаю данные

```
repositoriesList.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest('.repositories-list__link')) {
        let fullRepoName = event.target.textContent;
        new API().getRepoResult(fullRepoName).then(createRepoCard);
    }
})
```

Здесь после клика я получаю все данные и заношу в localStorage

```
function getContributors(response) {
    let contributors = [];
    response.forEach((item) => {
        contributors.push(item.login);
    })
    console.log(contributors);
    localStorage.setItem('contributorsArr', JSON.stringify(contributors));
}

function createRepoCard(response) {
    new API().getContributorsResult(response['full_name']).then(getContributors);
    let repoData = {
        fullName: response['full_name'],
        avatarURL: response.owner['avatar_url'],
        owner: response.owner.login,
        stars: response['stargazers_count'],
        language: response['language'],
        description: response['description']
    }
    localStorage.setItem('repoInfo', JSON.stringify(repoData));
// Тот самый переход по ссылке, который не дожидается записи в contributorsArr
document.location.href = "/user.html";
}
```

Comment: Немогу оставить комент, вот похожий вопрос
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921220/is-any-solution-to-do-localstorage-setitem-in-asynchronous-way-in-javascript

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)